# keyboard & background

Tags: android

how could I set the background to not move ever.
I tried: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateVisible"`
but it exceeds the upper row.

and How can I delete the top row

[image: (where it says the app name)]

Comment: What about the keyboard? And to hide the toolbar, use an appropriate theme in the manifest

Comment: In case you don't know, the top row is called the toolbar. You need to hide it using theme in manifest or by writing appropriate code in activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this theme to hide toolbar

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
```

If you want to apply theme for single `Activity` then

```
<activity
            android:name=".ActivityName"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            ......................................................
            ...................................................... >
</activity>
```

If you want to use same theme for whole Android project then use

```
 <application
                android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
                ......................................................
                ...................................................... >
 </application>
```

Comment: hey. I want it only on one activity. what should I do?